# Mostrar valor y pasar ID en formulario

Tags: laravel, formularios

actualmente estoy haciendo el formulario de actualizacion de registros en mi sistema.

Estoy mostrando un formulario donde tengo que traer de que sucursal es el empleado. Lo estoy mostrando de la siguiente forma

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="sucursal_id" value="{{ $empleado->sucursal->name }}"></input>
```

Lo que me trae un input con el nombre de la sucursal, el tema es que cuando yo envio el formulario necesito enviar el id de la sucursal, para remplazarlo por el que se encuentra actualmente en $empleado->sucursal_id

Como hago para mostrar el nombre de la sucursal pero a la vez enviar el ID y no el valor, porque de esta manera el sistema explota.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes hacer lo siguiente:

1. Visualmente le puedes dejar al usuario un `input`con el nombre de la sucursal así como ya lo tienes:

Código

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="sucursal_id" value="{{ $empleado->sucursal->name }}" />
```

2. Ahora para mandar el dato real de la modificación, puedes meter el `id` de la sucursal en un `input` de tipo `hidden`; es decir al usuario ve el nombre de la sucursal, esta oculto el `id` y en tu controlador recibes el valor `id` de tu input tipo `hidden` así:

Código

```
<input type="hidden" value="{{ $empleado->sucursal_id }}" name="sucursal_id" />
```

Es decir en el método que procesa este formulario invocas a este último `input` a través de su `name` y así estarías recuperando el `id` en cuestión.

**Edición**

Con lo expuesto en el comentario:

Deberías tener una estructura similar a la siguiente:

Un `select` donde:

- A nivel de la etiqueta `select` le asignas un `name` que después nos servirá para recuperarlo desde el controlador
- En el `option` en tu atributo `value` estarías recuperando el `id` y como valor visible estarías mostrando el nombre para que sea visualmente identificable por el usuario

Así:

```
<select name="usuario">
    @foreach($data as $dato)
        <option value="{{ $dato->id }}">{{ $dato->name }}</option>
    @endforeach
</select>
```

Posterior en tu controlador donde estés captando esta información, pudieras recuperar el valor del `id` que finalmente es el que te interesa modificar de este modo:

```
public function lista(Request $request)
{
    return $request->input('usuario');
}
```

Donde como puedes observar recupera con el objeto `$request` el valor del `input` cuyo `name` es `usuario` y podrás comprobar que por cada elección del usuario del menú desplegable me mostrará o retornará un `id` distinto.

Comment: Ya lo modifique de la siguiente manera

<select name="sucursal_id" class="form-control">
    @foreach($sucursales as $sucursal) 
    <option value="{{$sucursal->id}}">{{$sucursal->name}}</option>
    @endforeach
   </select>

Ahora como hago para que se autoseleccione el valor que se encuentra almancenado, tal valor se encuentra en $empleado->sucursal->sucursal_id

Comment: ok @FrancoSanchez dame unos minutos, ¿qué tipo de relación estas manejando? Uno a muchos o uno a uno?

Comment: Uno a muchos, ya que un empleado pertenece a una UNICA sucursal, pero la sucursal posee VARIOS empleados.

Comment: Dejo la respuesta ya que lo resolvi
<option value="{{ $sucursal->id }}" {{ ( $sucursal->id == $empleado->sucursal_id) ? 'selected' : '' }}> {{ $sucursal->name }} </option>